# Is there a way to sync Zim on Ubuntu and an Android device?

Tags: notes

I'm looking for a way to sync Zim notes on my ubuntu with an android device, at least partially.
Actually it would be enough for me, if I can somehow sync task list of zim to android.

Well, using an alternative note-taking software might be another option, but among a lot of software claiming to be an alternative, I didn't see any one that is actually capable of replacing Zim. I need to be able to take notes and make to-do lists on the same page (or note) and also be able to see tasks (extracted from to-do lists on different pages) together on another page ordered wrt due dates.